# Start failed for Job in SQL Server Agent

Tags: stored-procedures, ssms, sql-server-agent, errors, jobs

I am trying to schedule a job which executes stored procedure but it is failing.

```
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_WarehouseAttendance_New]
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

If I try to run it manually,  I am getting this error.

[image: Manually Execute Job Error]

At the moment I am trying to run `EXECUTE storedproc` but it takes long time to complete.

I checked Services.msc and it shows as below.

[image: Services.msc]

Kindly let me know how to avoid this.

Thanks,
Ar

Comment: ,Make sure that the value of the Status column of the SQL Server Agent service is Running  in services.msc .

Comment: Haidar - Please look above I cannot change the Status :(

Comment: SQL Server Agent (and other SQL Server services) is different from most other services, you control it from SQL Server Configuration manager. I think SQL Server Agent *is* running, as it is accessible (green, with jobs listed below) in Management Studio, as shown in your original screenshot, if it were not running, it would not be accessible (red). I do not believe this is the problem.

Comment: @Aruna Raghunam,Have you try through properties->start the sql server agent services

Comment: @Ian_H, As screen shot of OP there is two SQL server agent services. And one is disabled and second one is not running. That's means sql server agent service is not running of OP throng windows services.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan I'm afraid I'll refer you to my original comment. SQL Server is not a 'normal' windows service. There's two SQL server agent services there because the OP has at least two installations of SQL Server on that box (two instances of SQL Server). One being disabled, and one running (as per the green, accessible Agent in management studio). SQL Server services need to be managed through Config manager, not usually Windows Services

Comment: I really think this is a red herring, the OP should try the course I suggest in the answer below.

Comment: @ArunaRaghunam, If you are using windows server OS and powershell is working in your environment then you can check through powershell . what are sql services are 'Running' or 'Stopped' through this command. (for example PS H:\> get-service *sql*) here H is a Drive name.

Comment: @ArunaRaghunam I'm afraid I think you're getting bad info in these comments. I'm going to leave this discussion here as it's got lengthy, and the comments are not meant for answers anyway. This is not the problem, Agent is running fine, and is not started from windows services, you use config manager. If you don't take my word for it, listen to MS (we shouldn't even need to be having this discussion) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178142(v=sql.110).aspx  OR https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191454(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan I don't have any more info than you, but as you can see from his original screenshot, all his jobs are listed, that would not happen, and the error he got would not occur, if Agent wasn't running. Besides, you still use Config manage to manager SQL Server services, NOT windows services. Also, comments are not the place for answers, the answer is below, which responds to the original error. This has got silly so I'm leaving it here, read the links (from Microsoft) and it'll prove my point

Comment: Jobs were running fine till server was restarted last week. I am facing this issue after that...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is exactly in the description - the job is already running.

Try stopping the job first, then re-running it. Either with the GUI, or

```
USE msdb 
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_stop_job
    N'Job Name' 
GO
```

Other things to check:
What is the job doing? Can you do that (run the script, for example) directly (not using Agent)?

Has the job got elements (e.g. a script) which can never actually finish, therefore the job is never going to stop (and therefore will not start again on schedule).

It's a bit hacky, but you can schedule a job-killing job to stop any jobs that are over-running (although it's usually better to try fix your jobs so they finish properly).

This script from [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlstudies/2013/09/05/a-t-sql-query-to-get-current-job-activity/) provides some handy info about currently running jobs:

```
SELECT
    ja.job_id,
    j.name AS job_name,
    ja.start_execution_date,      
    ISNULL(last_executed_step_id,0)+1 AS current_executed_step_id,
    Js.step_name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh 
    ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON ja.job_id = js.job_id
    AND ISNULL(ja.last_executed_step_id,0)+1 = js.step_id
WHERE ja.session_id = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC)
AND start_execution_date is not null
AND stop_execution_date is null;
```

That should help you sort out your problem, if not, post some more details about what exactly the job is doing.

Edit-
Code to check SQL server agent is running (run from Management studio).
DECLARE @agent NVARCHAR(512);

```
SELECT @agent = COALESCE(N'SQLAgent$' + CONVERT(SYSNAME, SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')), 
  N'SQLServerAgent');

EXEC master.dbo.xp_servicecontrol 'QueryState', @agent;
```

You can manage Agent from SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Ian

Comment: I ran the above SQL and it gives me SQLServerAgent Error: Request to stop job AttendanceWarehouse_New (from User EFC\araghunam) refused because the job is not currently running.                                      I ran above script and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Ian_H,As OP screen shot sql server agent service is not running. Running status icon should be like that ( for your ref i am sending mssql tips link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2445/sql-server-multi-server-administration/) or http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Checking%20the%20status%20of%20SQL%20Server%20Agent%20jobs.aspx

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan Nothing actually indicates it's not running yet - and nothing that you said would help that. Those links are not relevant

Comment: @ArunaRaghunam to put this to bed, I'll add some code to the answer which will check whether agent is running on that server. If you want to check, find SQL Server Configuration manager in windows (not services), as that's where you start and stop Agent (and indeed SQL server). It probably wouldn't hurt to try restarting Agent (but you do it that way, NOT from windows services)

Comment: @Ian - I saw your link to start SQL Server Agent from SQL Configuration Manager but I do not see SQL Agent listed...

Comment: @Ian - I ran above Code and it shows Current Service State as Running...

Comment: @ArunaRaghunam yes I thought it was, just thought I'd rule that out once and for all! Check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/653571/Understanding-SQL-Server-Configuration-Manager which describes config manager, and should help your understanding of how that works - but I don't think it's that (you could post a screenshot of your config manager just to be sure though). Try running the kill code again (and check for certain that nothing is running), and then try running your job again - see what results you get from that, and post the error (it should be different from your original)

Comment: @Ian - I tried to run/start the job manually but it takes forever to run so I just stopped it and now get 'Lock timeout period exceeded error' :(